# How to properly escape image path in tailwind.config.js file?

Tags: tailwind-css

I tried adding a background image property to my tailwind.config.js file by writing the path to my image which uses backslashes (am on windows). I tried escaping with double backslashes (\) but it doesn't seems to work. Here's a snippet of my code:
[image: screenshot of tailwind.config.js code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `public` folder is needed, as it's considered as the root folder.
You should use regular slashes, no need to put backslashes or escape them. source: [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme)
Also, is that `heroImage` needed multiple times in the project? If not, you can try using [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values) instead.

Comment: what about when its needed multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

`tailwind.config.js` generally uses CSS values and functions. The `url()` function should take a value that uses forward slashes, like any URL you'd type into your browser.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url

Comment: What about the jss aspect? I'm getting, 
`ul: { listStyleImage: "url('/assets/img/icon-pyramid-bullet.png')" }`
I'm getting `ReferenceError: url is not defined`